# Displaying numberlists in sort=none glossaries

Tags: glossaries, glossaries-extra

I'm trying to create an index of notation for a project on overleaf using the glossaries package. Because most of the entries are not English letters or in abnormal fonts, and because overleaf apparently isn't compatible with bib2gls, I've been using the following setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort=none]{glossaries-extra}
\newglossaryentry{alpha}{name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},
description={blah}}
\begin{document}
\gls{alpha}
\printunsrtglossary
\end{document}
```

However, I would like to display a numberlist, which I currently don't know how to do.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.... Sorry, can you show some screenshot or image for your requirement? please...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I just want a page number to appear after the description of each symbol in my glossary.  Like in most of these examples: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries

Answer (score 1):

Hope this may helps you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{alpha}{name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},
description={blah}}
\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\gls{alpha}
\printglossary
\end{document}
```

Please do execute the below steps:

```
latex/pdflatex filename.tex

makeindex -s filename.ist -o filename.gls filename.glo

latex/pdflatex filename.tex
```

Comment: Thanks @MadyYuvi  I guess one issue with this approach is that the sorting will be very random because I'm using lots of greek letters and math scripts.